# Linux, PHP 8.2 - mbstring warning running Laravel dev server

Tags: php, laravel, php-8, mbstring

I'm on ElementaryOS (basically Ubuntu) and have PHP 8.2 installed. I'm trying to get the mbstring extension. When I install it, it says I already have it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
php8.2-mbstring is already the newest version (8.2.12-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  javascript-common libc-ares2 libjs-highlight.js libnode72 nodejs-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 435 not upgraded.
```

However, phpinfo said that it's disabled:

```
Multibyte decoding support using mbstring   disabled
```

And I was receiving errors on my website related to not having this extension.

I uncommented `;extension=mbstring` in the php.ini file and now it says that it's enabled. However, starting the Laravel dev server emits this warning:

```
$ php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

   WARN  PHP Warning: Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0.  

   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].  

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

What does this warning mean and is there a way to get rid of it but still use mbstring?

Comment: edit your `php.ini` and activate that extension

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly now I have a new issue... edited my question

Comment: Did you add it twice, check the complete `php.ini` file they often contain useful info lines that can be confused with the actual parameter lines

Comment: I only uncommented one line so I don't think I added it twice..